# Not able to align divs' inside a parent div in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Here is the picture. I want to align the div's (with blue border) from top. I just want the CSS code for this. I tried to use margin but its not working. Also when more content is inserted inside these div's they expand from bottom to top, seems like bottom for these div's  is fixed or something.

what I want is that the Inner div's (with blue border) should be top aligned not bottom aligned and when more text is added inside these div's it should expand from top top to bottom.

[image: here.]

[image]

here is the CSS code. **propertiesContainer** class is the parent div with red border and **properties** class are the inner div's

```
propertiesContainer: {
  paddingTop: "26px",
  background: " #EAEAFA",
  border: "1px solid red",
  opacity: 1,
},
properties: {
  bottom: "100px",
  margin: "19px",
  width: "auto",
  border: "2px solid blue",
  height: "262px",
},
```

Reactjs code for this

```
<section className={classes.propertiesContainer}>
  <HorizontalScroll
    itemClass="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12"
    data={
      mobile_footer_data &&
      mobile_footer_data.map((data, index) => {
        const { header, body } = data;
        console.log("dataa", data);

        const text = body.map((item, index) => {
          return <div key={index}>{item}</div>;
        });

        return (
          <div key={index} className={classes.properties}>
            <CommonHeaderText
              text={<span>{header}</span>}
              variant="h1"
              style={{
                fontSize: "16px",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                fontFamily: "Open Sans",
                color: "##363636",
                height: "19px",
                marginBottom: "25px",
              }}
            />

            <div>{text}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    }
  />
</section>;
```

Comment: Try to learn flexbox, it will help you to align the div as you want

Comment: share your HTML as well

Comment: basically I am using the CSS grids for this. But the problem is still persisting

Comment: added the code @AhsanKhan

Comment: In your code you don't use grid system...Please give us a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inline element, The default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`. So, they are text baseline aligned. Trying applying this to the child div:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

```css
        .outter {
            outline: 2px dashed #387779;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .inner {
            width: 100px;
            height: 80px;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #a3af92;
            color: #26310a;
        }
        .vtop {
            vertical-align: top;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="outter">
        <div class="inner">hello<br/>world<br/>abc</div>
        <div class="inner">abcd<br/>two</div>
        <div class="inner">123</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="outter">
        <div class="inner vtop">hello<br/>world<br/>abc</div>
        <div class="inner vtop">abcd<br/>two</div>
        <div class="inner">123</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your parent div has className "parent"
and it has two children "child1" and "child2"
so the css will look like this

```
.parent{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-between;
   align-items:flex-start;
}
```

Trying applying this to the parent div , hope this solves your issue .

Comment: I am using grids, I can't use flex

Comment: can you make a sandbox and send the link ... so that I can understand it more better

Comment: sorry I can't do that, but thanks for that